# TabBar has a gray line?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarViewController with a custom backgroundimage, but when I set this there is an gray line - the shadow line? - on the default place, where it should be and the image is to large on screen!
The size is 320x50px, so it should be the exact size.
Clip subviews doesn't work at all...

Comment: Have you subclassed your ``UITabBar``? Do you set it's size somewhere?

Comment: No, I haven't...
Do I have to?